# limit access to private files uploaded by webform to specific role

Tags: webforms, users, files

In my Drupal 7 site, I have a webform where anonymous users upload a file
(typically, their CV). The webform is configured to save it in the private file system. How can I achieve that the uploaded files are accessible only to authenticated users who belong to a specific role ?
(at this moment they are accessible only to the admin user)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, users with the 'access all webform results' permission can view all webform private files.

If, for some reason you need them to be able to access the files but not the webform results, you could implement `hook_file_download()` - you could base your implementation on `webform_file_download()` in webform.module

Answer (score 0):

Think you need [Private files download permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission)

Comment: Thx. I came across several modules, but not this one. I will check this.

Comment: This doesn't work. It might work for standard node attachments, but I think that the webform module has its own hooks for controlling access, and once access is denied the 'Private files download permission' module doesn't seem to be able to overrule.

Comment: I'm thinking of implementing my own hooks in my custom module...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use [Permissions per Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_per_webform) and then limit accessing all results for that particular webform to the roles that you need.

The only issue at that point would be if you had multiple roes needing multiple levels of results access.